# Birt Report Multiple Parameters for the same field

Tags: eclipse, date, parameters, birt

I am using Birt to generate reports. I want to use the same parameter twice in my where clause e.g. where date_column >= ? and date_column < ?. The '?' at this line is one parameter which points to a date (Report parameter). Adding to this in my next where clause I want to use a second parameter to find the date period again but in a different year (current year -1). I know that birt sees parameters and ? sequentially. How can I configure this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add two parameters with 2 diffenrent names to your query and use the same source(Report-Paramter) for both of your parameters. There is no restriction, that you cannot add the same paramter multiple times to your query.

Add as many `?` in your SQL query as you need parameters:

[image: SQL query with parameters]

In the Parameters Tag you can link them to your Report-Input-Parameters as you like and also add a Input-Parameter twice. The `?` in your query will be replaces by the values of your parameters in the order of appereance (first `?` = first parameter, second `?` = second parameter etc.):

[image: add parameters to sql query]

Comment: How can I do this in Birt. I mean add two different names of parameters in my query?

Comment: in your SQL query you use `?` for both parameters. the first `?` will be replaces by your first parameter and the second `?` with your second parameter.

Comment: so instead of using the '?' i should use the name of the parameter used in the dataset e.g. 'date_1' and 'date_2'?

Comment: @charilaos13: no, in the sql query you always use `?` as place holder. See my update with pictures. I hope this helps you to understand the doing.