# Reusing parameters more than once

Tags: postgresql, birt, with-statement

I am writing a report in BIRT. I have two input parameters on my data set.

The second parameter I would like to use twice in my **where** clause. I found I cam do this using a **with** clause. Note this is a postgresql database so I do not need **from dual**.

My sql is as follows:

```
with "params" as (select ? as "sname", ? as "ename")
select "user"."fullName", "user"."address1", "user"."address2", "user"."city", "provinces"."abbreviation", "user"."postalcode", "client"."companyName"
from "user", "params"
LEFT JOIN "client" on "user"."client" = "client"."id" 
LEFT JOIN "provinces" on "user"."province" = "provinces"."id"
WHERE "user"."fullName" >= "params"."sname" and (("user"."fullName" <= "params"."ename") or ("params"."ename" =''))`
```

When I try to run this or preview the results in BIRT's edit data set screen I get the following error:

> Error happened while running the report.
>       at ....
>   Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.api.AdapterException: An exception occurred during processing. Please see the following message for details:
>   Failed to prepare the query execution for the data set: user
>   Cannot get the result set metadata.
>       org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: SQL statement does not return a ResultSet object.
>   SQL error #1:ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "user"
>     Hint: There is an entry for table "user", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
>     Position: 252;

I can't get by this. From everything I have seen it should work.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you can do the CTE even shorter: `with params (sname, ename) as (values (?, ?) ) ...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mixing explicit and implicit joins fails with "There is an entry for table ... but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347897/mixing-explicit-and-implicit-joins-fails-with-there-is-an-entry-for-table-b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add multiple parameters in your SQL-Query in Birt and reuse an Input-Parameter from Birt as often as you want. [Compare my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36181862/1515052).

So you can write your query without the `with-clause` and prevent the mixing of explicit and implicit joins:

```
select "user"."fullName", "user"."address1", "user"."address2", "user"."city", "provinces"."abbreviation", "user"."postalcode", "client"."companyName"
from "user"
LEFT JOIN "client" on "user"."client" = "client"."id" 
LEFT JOIN "provinces" on "user"."province" = "provinces"."id"
WHERE "user"."fullName" >= ? and (("user"."fullName" <= ?) or (? =''))
```

Comment: This sort of worked. Although Birt was not picking up that my second Parameter was = ''. So I defaulted the parameter to null and changed the end of the where clause to : 

`select "user"."fullName", "user"."address1", "user"."address2", "user"."city", "provinces"."abbreviation", "user"."postalcode", "client"."companyName"
from "user"
LEFT JOIN "client" on "user"."client" = "client"."id" 
LEFT JOIN "provinces" on "user"."province" = "provinces"."id"
WHERE "user"."fullName" >= ? and (("user"."fullName" <= ?) or (? is null))`

Comment: I solved it all now. Thank you for your assistance. Wish I had found your earlier solution.